# "Submit" for review button grayed out - Xcode 6

Tags: app-store, submit, xcode6, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit my first app for iOS 8 and i am going through the new procedure of Apple's iTunes connect. I have upload my binary, fill all the details and upload all screenshots. Then i press submit for review and I see this screen with 2 option. Whatever I select the "submit" button stays greyed out.

[image]

Comment: is anybody else having this problem? are we missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apple made a HTML coding mistake on this page.  Specifically they forgot a quote on one of the tags making the HTML invalid.  Using FireFox you can change the HTML and then the submit works.  I submitted my app this way just now and  it is "Waiting for Review"!

On the Export Compliance Tag they are missing a quote (") after the "section" in a tag.  If you add that (") in the Inspector on FireFox (or using similar methods on other browsers to modify the HTML you are looking at) the Export Compliance question will show up and then you can answer it and submit your app.

OR you could just wait till tomorrow and Apple will probably fix their HTML coding mistake.

Comment: This problem is still occurring and its 2017. Didn't Apple fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Removed just one "ng-hide" tag to enable third question about Export Compliance and the button submit appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution for this.
Last night also I tried to upload the build on App Store. I left the window idle for 2 hours after uploading the build and the button appeared. Seems to be a bug or feature in the new upload system.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this through Chrome? Try Safari and you should get three options and the submit button will be available when all three are checked

Comment: no i am trying with safari.

Comment: I had the same with Chrome, tried Safari and it was fine.  Delete your cache

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Wow has iOS8/XCode 6 launch been a mess.

Answer (score 0):

It's and interface bug by Apple. (Wow, Apple) I cannot reach the page again so I can only give so much detail on how I could get through it and submit: I opened up Chrome inspector on the page to look at the HTML, looked for the "cryptography" string as the mistakenly hidden question is about that. I removed the "ng-hide" class off of some of the tags, and finally the crytography question appeared. (Along with the "Is your app going to be sold in the French App Store?" question for some reason.) I checked no, and the submit button was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

We may have caught Apple in a middle of a deployment. It looks like they added a new question to this page for "Export Compliance". Either way, it looks like they fixed the submit button now.

[image]