# Change New App Version number in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I believe I managed to somehow put myself in some kind of weird dead lock in iTunes Connect.

I have an app with 2.14 as the current version. After writing an update, I decided to number the new version 2.2. iTunes Connect allowed me to do this.

When I tried to validate the new version, it told me that in the iTunes connect world 2.2 is not higher than 2.14. That is OK and I was more than willing to change the numbering when compiling to 2.20. However, when I submit, it doesn't upload to the version build section on the page.

I want to change the new version number so it would fit with the number I have when compiling, or remove the new version so I can make a new one - but there is no where to do it on the panel!!!

Please help me.

Comment: May it have to do with this other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286454/submit-for-review-button-grayed-out-xcode-6

Comment: Yes, I believe Apple has corrected this now. 
May I just say - I hate the new iTunes Connect!!!

Comment: Me either, it's still too buggy ;)

Answer (score 7):

there is a Version field within the section "General App Information", below the App Icon File and Apple Id, you can change the number there