# Remove a build from itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

I wanted to submit my app in itunes connect and I uploaded a build. I haven't submitted the app for review and I found a bug on the app and wanted to upload a new build but I get the error of redundancy. From what I searched it is not possible to remove the build but I wanted to ask what if I delete the whole application and start over the process since I haven't submitted the app for review yet.
Thanks very much

Comment: Why not just update the build number?

Comment: @Thilo he can update the build number because it has not yet been submitted to the apple appstore

Comment: @Geet so we can delete the uploaded build? I thought this is impossible. but how?

Comment: Update the build Version number to something like 1.0.0.1 or something greater than 1 will remove your error....

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683441/how-to-delete-app-build-in-new-itunes-connect-site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't remove the build in itunes...If you want to apply a new build to itunes....Change build version in Xcode...(For example 1.1.1) and you can see all your build in itunes,
Next to Version,you can see an option "Prerelease".

Comment: Thanks very much , by changing the build number I could upload new build without changing the version

Answer (score 8):

Well if you have not submitted your app for review, things are still in your hands. You should see a minus sign to remove build.

[image]

Remove your build form here.

Increase your build number in the xcode project (General Settings tab). Archive your build and submit it to iTunes.

[image]

You should see your build in `Prerelease` Section as it will be in processing state. After some time, it will appear in build list, and you can new build select from there. Hope it helps!

Comment: Do I need to submit ipa again for updated itunes connected version ? I mean if I added 3.11.2 and it is in status as "Prepare for Submission" and I have uploaded build for 3.11.2 it is working and it is in Test flight--- now at some later point my team decides lets have 3.12 without 3.11.2. How this should be handled ?

Comment: As long as you haven't submitted for review, you can configure your version. In "General App Information" section, change version number.

Comment: Thanks NightFury for the update ..  If I update version now then I need to upload new binary pointing to that version .. right ? I mean am updating 3.11.2 version in intunes connect to 3.12 from general app info section. Now, I should update the binary accordingly .. right ?

Comment: No, you don't need to update binary. Just change the version number. For more information, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48861708/437146) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289416/change-new-app-version-number-in-itunes-connect)

Comment: If I change version number, binary version will still be old .. right ? My app. will be pointing to old version .. but I want itunes connect version to be same as xcode binary version

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it would be possible to delete the application from itunes connect, I tried to do it once but wasn't able to, so what ended up doing was, I renamed the previous  application in itunes connect, and created a new application with the desired app name and a new bundle ID., and then uploaded the new build with the new provisioning profile. on itunes connect with the desired app name

Its not an ideal solution but it worked for me.