# How to replace my current version app with status “Prepare for Submission” with new version in itunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store

I uploaded the application with version number **1.2** and it got approved for release, So its status changed from “waiting for review” To “**Prepared for developer release**”. But due to some reasons I want to release the application with **1.3 not 1.2** and I don’t want to do the entire review process once again. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can easily do it without going to the entire review process. You just have to change the version in General Tab and you are good to go.

Just go to your app which has the status “Prepare for developer release” under the App Store Tab. > Scroll to General App Information. There you will see version field change it to whatever version you want. > Scroll up click to Save. Just make sure the new version must be greater from the version which is "ready for sale”.