# How to submit the app for review after the current version of the app is rejected?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

[image: Please find the Image here]

I uploaded a new build to AppStore Connect. Currently, the app is in the "prepare for submission" state. I uploaded all of the screenshots required and other things. I can only see the save button in AppStore Connect but the "submit for review" button is missing. How can we submit the app for review now?

Previous versions of the app were present in the App Store. I uploaded an update to the existing app but the current version was rejected. I fixed the issues and added a new build with current rejected version number and with the increased build number. But AppStore Connect only shows the Save button and I can't find the "submit for review" button.

Won't we see the "submit for review" button for rejected binaries?

Comment: How can I submit my app for review after it is rejected?

Comment: It's simple. Login on `itunesconnect`. Remove build which you have submitted to review and again add new build and submit for review again (First make sure your build is uploaded on `itunesconnect`).

Comment: First click on the save button then it will change to submit for review.

Comment: Please refer only screenshot here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499697/remove-a-build-from-itunes-connect?rq=1 By clicking on minus button build will be removed, then click on Save button on top right corner then again add new build -> Save -> and Submit

Comment: @MaheshV Can you post a screenshot? submit for review button is disabled or not shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After the app rejection, only the admin or manager of the AppStore connect account can submit the app for review.** I was assigned with only developer role and hence was unable to submit the app for review again.

Answer (score 0):

When Apple rejects an app, they specify the reason of the rejection. So you need to make changes said by apple in order to submit app again to App Store.

The uploading process is same as when you submitted the previous build but the only thing you need to take care of if *app version*.

You need to change the app version (generally it should be increased by one from the previous number) and upload the app again.

Once you upload build on the App Store you will see it under **Activity** and it will marked as processing.

Once the processing is finished you can select that build to submit for review.

**Create New version (if required)**

[image]

**Select a build to submit for review**

[image]

You can remove the existing build and select a new build and save it.

Once all the required info. is completed just **Save** it and then **Submit for Review** button will be enabled (but it is not the case every time)

Comment: If app is rejected, there is no need to create a new version for uploading new build.

Comment: Submit for Review is not there to enable it. I can only see save button there.

Comment: I didn't create the new version. I uploaded the new build with increased build number. But nowhere I can see Submit for Review button.

Comment: Submit button comes after you click the Save button. FYI : Save button would be active only if you make any change on the page. Like adding a new build.

Comment: But I cant' see the Submit button itself. Will the save button itself changes the name  to Submit Button?

Comment: What happens when you click the save button ?

Comment: Only saves the recent changes and it will be disabled after saving.

Comment: And the Submit button besides it, does it get enabled after saving ?

Comment: There is no submit button beside it.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Remove your rejected build from **Build** section which is above General App Information.
> 2. Add the new build you want to upload.
> 3. Click Save button.
> 4. You'll now see Submit for review screen.