# iTunes Connect Submit for Review Always Disabled

Tags: app-store-connect

I just uploaded my app on iTunes Connect.

My Prerelease build is **ACTIVE** (Apparently Apple forces you to use testflight or the build stays Inactive).

In the main version screen, I clicked `Submit for Review`.

- I clicked YES to the Content Rights Question.
- I clicked NO to the Advertising Identifier Question.

The **SUBMIT** button always stays disabled so I can never submit my App.

I did try different answers to these questions.

I'm using Mavericks with submission on Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stephane - looks like an Apple bug.
See - ["Submit" for review button grayed out - Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286454/submit-for-review-button-grayed-out-xcode-6)
And the answer by Chad Jones. Worked for me.